# IPV6-IPV4 tunneling

Tags: networking, ipv6, tunneling

I was assigned a task in which I need to implement an IPV6-IPV4 tunnel, it can be in Windows or Linux and then verify its operation with FPT or SHH service.

I'm thinking of doing it with an IPv6 tunnel broker like Hurricane Electric, but I'm not sure since there's not a lot of info around internet.  Can someone advise me on a good way to do it? Thanks.

Comment: check this out: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/6to4

Answer (score 0):

Here is a systemd service I wrote to create a tunnel.
You'll have to replace the w's, x's, y's and z's with your own address values obtained for Hurricane Electric

he-ipv6.service

---

```
[Unit]
Description=he.net IPv6 tunnel
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/bin/ip tunnel add he-ipv6 mode sit remote w.x.y.z local 192.168.11.100 ttl 255
ExecStart=/bin/ip link set he-ipv6 up mtu 1480
ExecStart=/bin/ip addr add 2001:470:www:xxx::2 dev he-ipv6
ExecStart=/bin/ip -6 route add ::/0 dev he-ipv6
ExecStop=/bin/ip -6 route del ::/0 dev he-ipv6
ExecStop=/bin/ip link set he-ipv6 down
ExecStop=/bin/ip tunnel del he-ipv6

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**